# Call Scala function from nodejs

Tags: node.js, scala

I am using node.js for writing restful service. I want to trigger clustering algorithm written in scala from this service.How can i call scala function from nodejs api

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! What did you try?

Comment: Do you want to call the process, or the output of [scala.js](http://www.scala-js.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

It's a broad question to answer it. 
But one way to achieve it is using a web service on top of your clustering algorithm.

You can check [spray.io](http://spray.io/) as a lightweigt webservice toolkit. It has embedded web server so you can start your application standalone.

Implement a simple rest service and make a http request to it from your node.js application.